# Extremely large ActiveMQ deployment performance issues

Tags: performance, activemq-classic, message-queue, spring-jms

We are planning to deploy an ActiveMQ farm capable of supporting 4+ million concurrent connections across many servers.  We are NOT using clustering based on our design.  The clients connect using MQTT and subscribe/consume to/from their own topic and publish to a shared virtual topic.  We are thinking of 100k connections and 20k msg/s per server.  I am nowhere near reaching that amount.  I have been successful connecting that amount, however its throughput that is hurting me.

To test, I am using a multithreaded client based around the Async (callback not future) version of the FuseSource MQTT client.  Using that client I am able to put a load on the system great enough that I see queue backlog.  I am getting the queue backlog using “java -jar activemq-all-5.13.0.jar dstat”.

I have tweaked the server in many ways but fail to be able to utilize all resources.  Iostat show low %util and top shows available cpu resources.

My server is running on a AWS m3.2xlarge (8vCPU, 30G ram).

I am starting activemq with “java –Xms12G –Xmx20G –jar …”

Here is how I am starting my broker.  Note that I have altered many setting but they don't seem to matter.

```
@Bean
public BrokerService getBrokerService() throws Exception {
    String hostname= InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

    // Create broker
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setBrokerName("ActiveMQ"+hostname);
    broker.setUseShutdownHook(true);
    broker.setAdvisorySupport( false );
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.setDeleteAllMessagesOnStartup( true );
    broker.setPopulateJMSXUserID( true );
    broker.setPopulateUserNameInMBeans( true );
    broker.setUseAuthenticatedPrincipalForJMSXUserID( true );
    broker.setUseVirtualTopics( true );

    // I have altered these but they don't seem to change anything.
    broker.setDedicatedTaskRunner( true );
    broker.setEnableStatistics( true );
    broker.setStartAsync( true );

    // Enable JMX bean
    final ManagementContext managementContext = new ManagementContext();
    managementContext.setCreateConnector(true);
    broker.setManagementContext( managementContext );        

    // Enable LevelDB
    broker.setPersistent( true );
    File dataFileDir = new File("/activemq/data/leveldb);
    LevelDBStore adapter = new LevelDBStore();
    adapter.setDirectory(dataFileDir);
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(adapter);

    // Turn flow control off
    PolicyEntry policy = new PolicyEntry();
    policy.setOptimizedDispatch( true );
    policy.setProducerFlowControl( false );
    policy.setGcInactiveDestinations( true );
    DispatchPolicy dp = new RoundRobinDispatchPolicy();
    policy.setDispatchPolicy( dp );
    PolicyMap policyMap = new PolicyMap();
    policyMap.setDefaultEntry( policy );
    broker.setDestinationPolicy( policyMap );

     // Set system usage
    SystemUsage memoryManager = new SystemUsage();
    MemoryUsage memoryUsage = new MemoryUsage();
    memoryUsage.setPercentOfJvmHeap( 75 );
    memoryManager.setMemoryUsage( memoryUsage );

    StoreUsage storeUsage = new StoreUsage();
    storeUsage.setLimit( 100*ONE_GB );
    memoryManager.setStoreUsage( storeUsage );

    TempUsage tempDiskUsage = new TempUsage();
    tempDiskUsage.setLimit( 100*ONE_GB );
    memoryManager.setTempUsage( tempDiskUsage );
    broker.setSystemUsage( memoryManager );

    // Add transports
    TransportConnector openwireconnector = new TransportConnector();
    openwireconnector.setName( "openwire" );
    openwireconnector.setUri(new URI("tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"));
    broker.addConnector(openwireconnector);

    TransportConnector mqttnioconnector = new TransportConnector();
    mqttnioconnector.setName( "mqtt+nio" );
    mqttnioconnector.setUri(new URI("mqtt+nio://0.0.0.0:1883"));
    broker.addConnector(mqttnioconnector);

    TransportConnector wsconnector = new TransportConnector();
    wsconnector.setName( "ws" );
    wsconnector.setUri(new URI("ws://0.0.0.0:61614"));
    broker.addConnector(wsconnector);

    // Start
    broker.start();
    broker.waitUntilStarted();
   return broker;
   }
}
```

I am using a spring JMS listener in another server which connects to ActiveMQ.

```
@Component
public class MqttMessageListener {
    @JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Message")
    public void processMessage(BytesMessage bytesMessage) {
     // I consume and discard here just for testing.  No work is being done to isolate issue.    
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
       DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency(“3-10”);  // I have tried many variation including 300-1000 although it seems to top out at 500.
    factory.setAutoStartup( true );
    return factory;
    }
}
```

With the above MqttMessageListener.processMessage method I am only able to consume at around 15k msgs/sec.  With 30+% cpu idle and low disk/network utilization I am unsure why I can't do better.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How can I find the limiting resource?
2. Is their an easy way to determine if this is an issue with ActiveMQ delivery or the consumption side?  Both are Spring Boot applications.

Comment: Hard to guess. You might want to try ActiveMQ Artemis instead which is supposed to handle high concurrency a bit better (non blocking). http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/